# Can we assign TextContext.TestDeploymentDir value to a static class data member?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I am very new to CodedUI test automation framework. I came across `TestContext` which has the important information regarding test result outputs and directories.
Actually i have created a static `Logger` class which writes output data to a `.txt` file. Now i want to create it under `TestResults` folder. Everytime i am running the test method it is creating a folder followed by some timestamp. I want to create my `Results.txt` file in that location.
Below is the code i am using :

```
public static class Logger
{

     string logLocation = TestContext.TestDeploymentDir + "\\Results.txt";


    static Logger() {
        File.Create(logLocation);
        using (var fs = new FileStream(logLocation, FileMode.Truncate))
        {
        }
    }

    public static void ResultLog(int testcasenum,String Expected,String Actual, String textResult)
    {

        FileInfo outtxt = new FileInfo(logLocation);

        StreamWriter logline = outtxt.AppendText();


        logline.WriteLine("Test Case : " + testcasenum);
        logline.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "Expected - "+Expected, "Actual - "+Actual, "Result - "+textResult);

        // flush and close file.

        logline.Flush(); logline.Close();


    }
}
```

Now i am getting a compile time error saying `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property TestContext.TestDeploymentDir.` Not sure how to resolve this error or whether it is possible or not ?

Comment: What is the constructor intended to do? The scope of `var fs` limited to the empty `using` block, so it has no useful effect beyond, possibly, emptying the output stream.

Comment: @AdrianHHH i am just truncating the log file. No specified logic to do anything. Just emptying the file here.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to mark `logLocation` as static since it is contained in a static class.  It's kind of silly but all members of a static class do also need to be marked static.  I believe this is to prevent confusion when reading larger classes where you cannot see the class declaration.  Next your current error message also says `TestContext`.`TestDeploymentDir` is not marked static and you'll need to modify that as well if possible.  If not you'll need to implement a singleton pattern to provide a static copy of an instance of that class.  Depending on the way that class works it may or may not be possible.

Comment: `TestContext` is an abstract class of system defined dll. Not sure if i can make any modifications in that. Also i have tried making `logLocation` as static but still it was showing same error.

Comment: So you're definitely going to need to keep `logLocation` static for sure.  You're just not getting that error yet since the compiler hasn't gotten that far.  If `TestContext` is an abstract class and `TestDeploymentDir` is an instance member (your error says so) you're going to need to implement the abstract class (inherit from it and implement any members marked abstract) and then create a singleton pattern to get you a static instance.  Then you can access that static instance in your field initializer. Little annoying, but entirely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a way to get the `out` path of `Coded UI` framework. Below is the code i have written :

```
public static class Logger 
{
    static string uripath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\Results.txt";
    public static string logLocation = new Uri(uripath).LocalPath;

    static Logger() {

        using (File.Create(logLocation))
        { }
        using (var fs = new FileStream(logLocation, FileMode.Truncate)){}
    }
    public static void ResultLog(int testcasenum,String Expected,String Actual, String textResult)
    {

        FileInfo outtxt = new FileInfo(logLocation);

        StreamWriter logline = outtxt.AppendText();


        logline.WriteLine("Test Case : " + testcasenum);
        logline.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "Expected - "+Expected, "Actual - "+Actual, "Result - "+textResult);

        // flush and close file.

        logline.Flush(); logline.Close();


    }
}
```

`uripath` will contain the same path as that of `TestContext.TestDeploymentDir`. Now `Results.txt` will come as an attachment in `Test Explorer` and we can see the output.